# Javascript - Adding variable to a string of code

Tags: javascript

I realized how bad I am with javascript :(

I have this:

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,     
function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}

var theidis = getUrlVars()["id"];
```

and

```
$.tzPOST = function(action,data,callback){
$.post('php/ajax.php?id='+theidis,'&action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
$.get('php/ajax.php?id='+theidis,'&action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}
```

The first gets the ?id=value parameter properly. I tested with an alert(theidis).

I am looking to do a simple thing - sorry if this is stupid -.- I have worked as this for so long that I am beginning to oversee things.

I want an ?id=value to be added to the php/ajax.php. I tried with the above, but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried by just adding it.

Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$.get` call specifies

```
'php/ajax.php?id='+theidis, '&action='+action, data ...
```

It looks like you're passing data twice. Either `&action='+action` should be your data parameter, or `data`. Did you mean to concatenate the `&action` part into the URL?

Comment: Hmm, they are three seperate functions. I know the script works with "theidis" removed. I am looking to - when calling the file - adding another parameter called ID to ID things in the database when running the script. Is it even possible? Or have I slammed my head voluntarily into a wall -.-

Comment: @Christian: [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) has the signature `get( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )`. So your first parameter is always your URL, which may contain additional data, by passing querystrings. If you want to add more data, you can do this in the second parameter. This could be a string or an object. You're currently passing `'&action='+action` as your second parameter. Then you're passing `data` which doesn't make sense when you've already passed string data. Your third parameter is supposed to be the callback.

Comment: So everything could be combined into +action?

Comment: @Christian: we don't know enough of your context here. Data is being passed to the server in the form `"variable=value&variable2=value"` and these can be sent either as form data or querystrings. By appending values to the URL you will be sending some querystring data, regardless of whether or not you specify `data`. But you could equally well have passed `'id='+theids+'&action='+action` as your data parameter, and left your url clean. Which approach you want to use depends on how your server is retreiving the values, what control you have over that, and what other data you want to send.

Comment: I see it. Hmm. Well I got some help with the script. But I know it works - it sends data from a form to a database with the help of those PHP-files. However, the only - and last thing - I need it to do to work properly is that is must choose a variable database. I have set it up so that

`$id` specifies which database in `ajax.php`. In `ajax.php` some files are required - and those files handles `data`, `action` etc. properly. I just need to add the `id` parameter to make e.g. the query 
`DELETE FROM ".$id."_chatusers` work.
Did that clarify? :-)

Comment: A bit. There are two entry points for sending data to the server, either through querystrings or by submitting form data. In `$.get` this can be achieved by the `url` parameter and the `data` parameter. I'm guessing that the script that was working before used querystrings in the URL for `action` and sent form data through the `data` parameter for the rest. Now, when you're adding ID, instead of tapping into one of the two parameters for sending data, you're creating a third parameter, which introduces an error. The easiest fix would probably be to concatenate `action` into your first param.

Comment: i.e. `$.get('php/ajax.php?id='+theidis+'&action='+action,data,callback,'json');`, and the same for `$.post`.

Comment: Thanks. Got it for the explanation :-)

Answer (score 1):

you probably meant:

```
$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
    $.get('php/ajax.php?id='+theidis + '&action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}
```

Change the `,` sign to `+` sign.

NOTE!: `data` should be null if you are cocncating string to the URL's query string.

Comment: I don't have the code here - but this should call in the ID? Data should be null? Sorry if that's a dumb question. :-)